# ionic native-serial returns device not found

Tags: android, ionic-framework, native, device, communication

The problem is:
 I want to establish communication between my desktop and my android smart device.

I'm trying a simple step but I get "device not found" as return

this is where I base my coding:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/serial/

this is the code:

> import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import {
>   NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; import {Serial} from
>   '@ionic-native/serial';
>
> @Component({   selector: 'page-home',   templateUrl: 'home.html' })
>   export class HomePage implements OnInit {   public status:string;
>   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public serial:Serial) {
>
> }
>
> ngOnInit(){
>   this.serial.requestPermission({vid:"04e8",pid:"6860",driver:"FtdiSerialDriver"})//I
>   already have tried to omit the request options but got the same error
>   .then(()=>{
>        this.status = "Permission requested"; //this would be the successfully result    }).catch(error=>{
>        this.status = error.toString(); // it's returning "device not found"    });   } }

there are few content about this feature on web.